# allConfigurations() in QNetworkConfigurationManager does not work in raspbian

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, raspbian

i use

```
allConfigurations()
```

for get list of All wireless ssid.
my code works on windows correctly but when use it in cross compile project that run on raspberry pi does not return wireless around me
what should i do?

this is reference link [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkconfigurationmanager.html#allConfigurations)

i figure out it always return "eth0" and "wlan0" in result
but i want return wireless SSIDs

Answer (score 0):

When you cross compile, don't forget to add the bearer plugin in your application folder. Else allConfigurations will return an empty list.